# OpenAI Chat Completions - None is not of type 'array' - 'functions'

Tags: openai-api

I can't seem to get OpenAI's Chat Completions HTTP API to accept my request. It's stuck on my `functions` property.

```
{
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "etc"
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "etc"
        }
    ],
    "functions": null,
    "function_call": null,
    "temperature": null,
    "top_p": null,
    "n": null,
    "stream": null,
    "stop": null,
    "max_tokens": null,
    "user": null
}
```

Produces a slightly nonsensical error,

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "None is not of type 'array' - 'functions'",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
}
```

But this JSON sent in,

```
{
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "etc"
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "etc"
        }
    ],
    "functions": [],
    "function_call": "none",
    "temperature": null,
    "top_p": null,
    "n": null,
    "stream": null,
    "stop": null,
    "max_tokens": null,
    "user": null
}
```

Gives this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "[] is too short - 'functions'",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
}
```

It doesn't like it either way?!

Funnily enough, I run it past GPT-3.5 itself and it said my JSON looks fine and shouldn't produce this error haha.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an odd API for the world's smartest people, it works when there is no `functions` property at all in the JSON.

This means adding this code for C# folks.

```cs
            var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
            };
```